# Liquibase insert select multiple rows postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I want to insert into `table1` multiple rows from `table2`. The problem is that I have some fields in `table1` that I want to compute, and some rows that I want to select from `table2`. For example something like this:

```
insert into table1 (id, selectField1, selectField2, constant)
values ((gen_random_uuid()), (select superField1 from table2), (select superField2 from table2), 'test');
```

So the logic is to select `superField1` and `superField2` from all the rows in the `table2` and insert them into `table1` with constant value `test` and generated uids. `superField1` and `superField2` should be from the same row in `table2` when inserting in `table1`. How can I achieve something like this using liquibase?

P.S: I'm using `<sql>` tag since it's easier to implement using SQL than using XML changeset, but if you know how to do it in XML that would be appreciated too, but just in SQL will be enough too. DBMS is postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the VALUES clause if the source is a SELECT statement:

```
insert into table1 (id, selectField1, selectField2, constant)
select gen_random_uuid(), superField1, superField2, 'test'
from table2;
```